# Why are LDS covenants and ordinances 'too sacred' to be discussed outside of the temples?

Tags: lds, liturgy, ordinances

Why are the covenants and ordinances of the LDS church 'too sacred' to be discussed in detail outside of the temples? I'm not aware of other Christian groups with such a secretive perspective on their beliefs and practices.

> You can talk about what the interior of the temple looks like, and you can freely share the feelings you have in the temple. However, temple covenants and ordinances, including the words used, are too sacred to be discussed in detail outside the temple. By avoiding discussion of these sacred things outside the temple, we protect them from mocking, ridicule, or disrespect. Do not be casual when talking about your experiences in the temple. ([lds.org](https://www.lds.org/church/temples/frequently-asked-questions?lang=eng))